# Why does locationManager.getBestProvider() returns null? (Nexus 5x)

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to get device (Nexus 5x) location by following a tutorial. But its not working and I found out, that the line

```
locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
```

always returns null.

Here is my manifest content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lt.wilkas.locationdemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my onCreate content:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //get best provider
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        if (provider == null) {
            Log.i("i", "provider ir null");
        } else {
            Log.i("i", provider);
        }
}
```

What am I doing not right?

Comment: You need to implement runtime permissions for Android 6.0 and greater.

Comment: Yes, GPS is on. Thank you for the lead Prerak, I will look for how to do that and will update question or enter answer myself.

Comment: If in your build.gradle file you use targetSdkVersion is 23 than you should use runtime permissions. If targetSdkVersion is less than 23 all should work

Comment: Thank you Beyka, your approach solved the issue with getBestProvider() returning "null". I'll include your suggestion in the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

1) One could update the value of `targetSdkVersion` to lower than 23 in a file "build.gradle". Thanks to **Beyka**.

2) Since Android 6.0 "dangerous" permissions should not only be included in the manifest file, but also asked for confirmation while App is running (Requesting Permissions at Run Time). Location provider should be asked only after getting runtime permission from the user. Thanks to **Prerak Sola**.

These are great resources and examples how to do that:

- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java